# Most commonly used tools for view development on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database that I build a lot of views on.

I currently write these views in straight SQL using SQL Server Management Studio.

My question is "are there other tools that developers commonly use to build SQL queries and views" ?

I'm really looking for an IDE for SQL.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a List for All Things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128561/158667)

Comment: There are numerous (more or less powerful) "replacements" for SQL Server Mgmt Studio - most try to be (a) free, (b) multi-database, or (c) something else, but none really fundamentally differ from what SSMS already offers. What's not "good enough" about SSMS that you want an "IDE for SQL" ???

Answer (score 1):

Do these count?

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/